# Mostrar valores sin repetir con DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy creando una función que me devuelva unos datos y los liste, pero necesito que solo sean datos únicos, que no se repitan...

```
dv = rut.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
$.post("Buscar_RutDepartamento", {rut: rut, dv:dv}, function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var ddpto   =   data[i].Ext_Nombre_Departamento;
        console.log("i "+ i);
        console.log(data);

        var text = document.createTextNode(ddpto);                                   
        document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(text); 
        document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
});
```

y ese es el `HTML`:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p class="help-block m-b-none obligatorio-on-texto" id="resultado"> </p>
</div>
```

el resultado es:

```
OFICINA PARTES
OFICINA PARTES
OFICINA PARTES
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
```

y quisiera que sea solo:

```
OFICINA PARTES
OFIC. CONCEJO MUNICIPAL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podría utilizar una variable temporal para hacer una comparación, así sabrás cuando no volver a mostrar el resultado.

```
dv = rut.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
$.post("Buscar_RutDepartamento", {rut: rut, dv:dv}, function(data){
  let temp = null;
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ddpto = data[i].Ext_Nombre_Departamento;

    // Verificar ultimo valor mostrado
    if(temp == ddpto) continue;
    else temp = ddpto;

    console.log("i "+ i);
    console.log(data);
    var text = document.createTextNode(ddpto);                                   
    document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(text); 
    document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
});
```

ó podrías utilizar un **Set** si los valores que se repiten no son subsecuentes

```
dv = rut.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
$.post("Buscar_RutDepartamento", {rut: rut, dv:dv}, function(data){
  const temp = new Set();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ddpto = data[i].Ext_Nombre_Departamento;

    // Verificar ultimos valores mostrados
    if(temp.has(ddpto)) continue;
    else temp.add(ddpto);

    console.log("i "+ i);
    console.log(data);
    var text = document.createTextNode(ddpto);                                   
    document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(text); 
    document.getElementById("resultado").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! funcionó la segunda opción

Comment: una consulta... si quisiera filtrar (es decir que me muestre todos los valores no repetidos, menos el valor de cierto select) Como puedo hacerlo ?

Comment: Depende del comportamiento que estés buscando, pero voy a suponer que el select ya estará con un valor seleccionado para cuando llegue a esta parte del código, así que simplemente tendrías que añadir estos valores al inicializar el `Set` :  `const temp = new Set(["valor1", "valor2"]);` en este ejemplo no se mostrarían "valor1" ni "valor2"